# Java JFrame actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I'm not used to Java and JFrame as I'm just starting to learn.

My question is that, I have error at the method `actionPerformed`. The error given is at the `e.getsource == b` I believe.

From what I understand, the button I created at the `public static void main(String[] args)` doesn't passed the value of the button to the `actionPerformed`.

I'm sorry if my question is not clear.

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    JButton b = new JButton("Click here");

    JFrame newWindow = new JFrame("Test");

    newWindow.setVisible(true);
    newWindow.setSize(250,250);
    newWindow.setLayout(null);

    newWindow.add(b);

    b.addActionListener(this);

}
```

Here is another part of my code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if ( e.getSource() == b )
    { 
        //do something 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you implemented ActionListener interface?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3) *"I'm sorry if my question is not clear."*  What 'question'?

Comment: @Masud yes I do implement ActionListener interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand, the button I created at the public static void
>   main(String[] args) doesn't passed the value of the button to the
>   actionPerformed.

**Yes**, you are right. The JButton object `b` is not visible at `actionPerformed` method. You need declare `b` globally.

```
   class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
      // Declare here to make visible to actionPerformed
      JButton b = new JButton("Click here"); 

       MyClass(){    
        super("Test");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(250,250);    
       }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         if ( e.getSource() == b ){ 
         //do something 
         }
       }
       public static void main(String[] args){
            new MyClass();
       }
   }
```

Comment: I see, but when I declare the `b` globally, the `newWindow.add(b)` gives me error. May I know anyway for me to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Now I can't compile because it doesn't have main method. One more question, the file I created is a normal blank .java file. Will it affect when I try to run the file without a `main` method?

Comment: @user273371, main method has added. File name should be MyClass.java.

Comment: Thank you so much @Masud. I'm sorry for stupid questions being asked as I'm new to Java and JFrame.

Comment: Welcome. Keep learning. Every great success has small beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It is `e.getSource()`. It is a method and all methods end in parentheses `()`.

Also, `b` is not visible in `actionperformed()`. Make it a global variable i.e. define it outside of `main()` and make it `static` so as to be able to access it in `main()`

Plus, as `Masud` asked, did your class implement the `ActionListener` interface ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgotten the `()` when I typed out my question. I didn't copy the full code as it is long.

Comment: So, Masud's question remains. Did your class implement action listener ?

Comment: I've follow your points (make `b` global and make it static) now the `b.addActionListener(this)` gives me error. May I know if anything I did is wrong.